# Copy Charts from one sheet to another and align it properly within target sheet. Target Sheet is having multiple shapes inserted

Tags: excel, vba

I am newbie to VBA programming and I want to prepare a Dashboard in Excel Sheet for which I have already prepared Data using Pivot table. What I need a VBA code that copies my chart from Sheet1 and paste it in Dashboard Template Sheet and align it in one of the shapes in Dashboard Template Sheet. I was able to copy paste the chart only. I want this dynamic so no matter how many time I run macro chart gets copied and aligned there without having problem of Chart no. or its index.

```vb
Dim chrt1 As ChartObject
Dim chrt2 As ChartObject
Dim chrt3 As ChartObject
Dim chrt4 As ChartObject

Set chrt1 = Sheets("Excess_DT").ChartObjects(1)
Set chrt2 = Sheets("DT Allowed Vs DT Punched").ChartObjects(1)
Set chrt3 = Sheets("Excess DT %").ChartObjects(1)
Set chrt4 = Sheets("Analyst Count").ChartObjects(1)

ActiveWorkbook.ShowPivotTableFieldList = False
chrt1.Select
chrt1.Copy
Sheets("Final Dashboard").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Set targetchart1 = Sheets("Final Dashboard").ActiveChart
targetchart1.IncrementLeft 397.8571653543`
```

only these codes i was able to write. I have attached my blank Dashboard template. Kindly help how should I do this.

[image: Dashboard Template]

As I mentioned I am newbie so couldn't do much. ChatGPT producing incorrect codes so am not sure whether its due to its free version or not.

Comment: Please provide 4 shapes' name and mapping with charts. Do you prefer to have charts or images on dashboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a better solution for this than using VBA ... use the Excel 'Camera' tool. The Camera tool provides a 'live snapshot' of any range of cells (or anything on top of that range of cells eg Charts in your case). Just to be clear, despite its name, the 'Camera' is more like a 'video feed' than a 'camera' ... the result is a real-time update of your existing Charts, not a fixed snapshot of them. And you can add as many of these as you need.

The 'Camera' tool, though, is not on any menu by default. So first you have to add it (I suggest to the QAT though you can add to the ribbon itself):

- File > Options > Quick Access Toolbar
- Under 'Choose commands from' select 'All commands'
- Scroll down to find 'Camera'
- Click 'Add>>' then OK
  ... you will now see a small camera icon in the QAT

Before using the Camera, ensure your 'source' Chart (eg on the "Excess_DT" sheet) is positioned perfectly over a rectangular range of cells then select those cells (using the keyboard ... if the Chart is positioned perfectly over a rectangular range of cells then selecting those cells with the mouse isn't possible as you will just keep selecting the Chart itself).

Click the camera icon in the QAT. You'll notice that your mouse icon / pointer changes to a very fine / small '+' instead of the usual icon.

Click on the tab for your dashboard sheet then draw a rectangle using the mouse (you can resize and reposition this later just as though it is a normal 'shape') so don't worry where you position it at first. This newly added 'camera shape' is a live image of the source chart / cells you originally selected from the "Excess_DT" sheet. You can then repeat this for the other 3 sheets / charts and, of course, you can replace the 4 purple shapes that you already have with these 'camera shapes'.

If you didn't get your 'source' chart positioned perfectly over a range of cells then you can go back to the 'source' and adjust the positioning and the 'camera shape' will update automatically.

Once you have it all set up, your dashboard will update in real time with no VBA.